# Modify string with PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have many strings and i would like use str_replace or others functions for replace text in this string without words with '@'.

I seperated words with ";".

How is the best method to make this?

I can't use for this replace "aaa;" because in $three i have "hhh" without ";".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
preg_replace('/aaa(?!@)/', '555', $1);
```

This regex will match whatever you replace `aaa` with but the `(?!@)` bit means that it won't match `aaa` if it is followed by an `@` symbol.

Comment: My mistake, typo in my answer. I have edited it. Check: http://codepad.org/6N7arpvc